# Rabbitmq or Ejabberd, which one should i use for one to one chat?

Tags: xmpp, rabbitmq, chat, amqp, ejabberd

I am searching Rabbitmq(amqp) and Ejabberd(xmpp) for a couple of days. But i couldn't figure out which one could be the best approach for one to one chat?

When a user visits a web page, the user will communicate with web page admin(if he/she is online) via using my chat tool. web admin can answer multiple visitors at same time in different chat rooms. but visitors can not talk each other, they can only talk to web admins.

which one (rabbitmq or ejabberd) is the best suited for these kind of needs? 
and which way should i use to implement it? (one exchange multiple queue for everything, different exchanges and queues for every visitor and web admin)?

Regards

Comment: If you just want a chat, then Ejabberd is built with that use case in mind. RabbitMQ is a more generic messaging server

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i need more detail and a comparison between them. Performance scalebility and integration with other systems ex spring or log stash

Comment: It is possible develop a chat application with rabbitmq. Then why do i need to use ejabberd or anything which uses xmpp?

Comment: Q: Can you make a chat with RabbitMQ. A: Yes.
Q: Can you integrate RabbitMQ with Spring. A: Yes. RabbitMQ is developed by the same company that develops Spring.
Q: Can you integrate RabbitMQ with logstash. A: Yes.

Otherwise most of the questions can have varying opinions depending who you ask. The best is always to run your own benchmarks

Comment: Thanks for your comments. What about ejabberd? Which one prvides a better design?

Comment: I work for RabbitMQ so, I'll be commenting only about RabbitMQ ;-)

Comment: Then could you direct me to a link to understand rabbitmq well to make a better design? Do i need to open queues for every member? 2 queues per chat? How can i understand admin is online? Have Lots of questions but not enough source

Comment: Take a look at this link http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html and our tutorials http://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html  The book RabbitMQ in Action explains how to build a chat on the last chapter. We maintain a user group for questions here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users

Comment: ok then, thanks for the links, i'll check them. let's wait someone who works for ejabberd :) or someone who uses both of them for one-to-one or group chat.

Answer (score 3):

For a chat service, you need to connect from clients to the server. XMPP is just done for that. It offers a protocol taylored for clients, for various environment (desktop, web, mobile).

AMQP is not designed for that. It is more taylored at infrastructure and back-ends communications.

Comment: Using websockets(stomp, any js library) and spring as a proxy in front of ejabberd makes any different such as performance or scalibility?

Comment: My comment was not about scalability. However, yes adding a proxy in front ejabberd will likely limit scalability to the scalability of your proxy.